# Is it possible to use Cubic bezier for animation in compose?

Tags: android, android-compose

I am wondering how to use Cubic bezier in android compose for animations?

Mostly about touch effect of one object, for instance, on a button press or animate it. Also, is there any stable library to import/add to grade and use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a good starting point: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/package-summary#top-level-properties-summary